# SSL Handshake failure after ClientHello

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception, openjdk-11

I am using openJdk version 11.28 at the client side. While calling a web service deployed over https, I am getting Handshake failure. Nmap command for the web service provides below result:

[image]

I have enabled ssl,handshake logging in my java which is producing below logs:

```
15:02:04,638 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp256r1
15:02:04,638 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp384r1
15:02:04,639 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp521r1
15:02:04,639 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: sect283k1
15:02:04,640 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: sect283r1
15:02:04,640 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: sect409k1
15:02:04,641 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: sect409r1
15:02:04,641 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:831|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp256k1
15:02:04,648 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|WARNING|D2|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
15:02:04,648 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|WARNING|D2|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
15:02:04,663 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|INFO|D2|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
15:02:04,664 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
15:02:04,666 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
15:02:04,668 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|ClientHello.java:633|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
15:02:04,668 ERROR  "ClientHello": {
15:02:04,668 ERROR    "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
15:02:04,669 ERROR    "random"              : "EE F5 C2 80 02 39 44 E5 C4 0E 65 EC 49 FF D0 38 A1 C7 2F 80 EA 5A F5 43 DC A1 4E C3 CB 42 7E 81",
15:02:04,669 ERROR    "session id"          : "",
15:02:04,669 ERROR    "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
15:02:04,669 ERROR    "compression methods" : "00",
15:02:04,669 ERROR    "extensions"          : [
15:02:04,670 ERROR      "server_name (0)": {
15:02:04,670 ERROR        type=host_name (0), value=mydomain.com
15:02:04,670 ERROR      },
15:02:04,670 ERROR      "status_request (5)": {
15:02:04,670 ERROR        "certificate status type": ocsp
15:02:04,671 ERROR        "OCSP status request": {
15:02:04,671 ERROR          "responder_id": <empty>
15:02:04,671 ERROR          "request extensions": {
15:02:04,671 ERROR            <empty>
15:02:04,671 ERROR          }
15:02:04,672 ERROR        }
15:02:04,672 ERROR      },
15:02:04,672 ERROR      "supported_groups (10)": {
15:02:04,672 ERROR        "versions": [sect571k1, sect571r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
15:02:04,672 ERROR      },
15:02:04,673 ERROR      "ec_point_formats (11)": {
15:02:04,673 ERROR        "formats": [uncompressed]
15:02:04,673 ERROR      },
15:02:04,673 ERROR      "signature_algorithms (13)": {
15:02:04,673 ERROR        "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
15:02:04,674 ERROR      },
15:02:04,674 ERROR      "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
15:02:04,674 ERROR        "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
15:02:04,674 ERROR      },
15:02:04,674 ERROR      "status_request_v2 (17)": {
15:02:04,675 ERROR        "cert status request": {
15:02:04,675 ERROR          "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
15:02:04,675 ERROR          "OCSP status request": {
15:02:04,675 ERROR            "responder_id": <empty>
15:02:04,675 ERROR            "request extensions": {
15:02:04,676 ERROR              <empty>
15:02:04,676 ERROR            }
15:02:04,676 ERROR          }
15:02:04,676 ERROR        }
15:02:04,677 ERROR      },
15:02:04,677 ERROR      "extended_master_secret (23)": {
15:02:04,677 ERROR        <empty>
15:02:04,677 ERROR      },
15:02:04,677 ERROR      "supported_versions (43)": {
15:02:04,678 ERROR        "versions": [TLSv1.2]
15:02:04,678 ERROR      }
15:02:04,678 ERROR    ]
15:02:04,678 ERROR  }
15:02:04,678 ERROR  )
15:02:04,693 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|D2|2020-05-16 15:02:04.692|Alert.java:232|Received alert message (
15:02:04,693 ERROR  "Alert": {
15:02:04,693 ERROR    "level"      : "fatal",
15:02:04,693 ERROR    "description": "handshake_failure"
15:02:04,693 ERROR  }
15:02:04,694 ERROR  )
15:02:04,696 ERROR  javax.net.ssl|ERROR|D2|2020-05-16 15:02:04.695| : Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
15:02:04,696 ERROR  "throwable" : {
15:02:04,696 ERROR    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
15:02:04,696 ERROR      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
```

I am unable to find out the reason behind Handshake failure. Please help to identify where the things have gone wrong during Handshake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later in our analysis, we found that issue was the openJdk version we were using. There were no common security groups between the client and server although there were matching cipher suites.

Below liink provides the information about the same thing.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8208698

Bug was fixed in version 12 and marked "jdk11u-critical-yes". Therefore we simply updated our JDK and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be cipher suite conflict at the web service end. It does not support tue ciphers which are enabled at the client side. Kindly capture the packets using wireshark to get a clear picture.